# Is it possible to block a phone from my app? Do phones have some ID that can be accessed?

Tags: java, android

Hello I ask this question because I have an app where people will have to post very serious stuff and if a user posts something that is not right, then I want to ban that person forever but how can I achieve that? Do phones have some type of identifier which I can retrieve from my app, check in the database and if that person was banned then I won't let that phone upload anything, or maybe blocking IP address? How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phones have many IDs but pretty much all of them can be reset in one form or another, your best bet is to collect all the ids and possibly the IP address and check all of them.  It's not fool-proof but the person would have to go through a lot of trouble to get around.  Although, even if there were a fool-proof way, they could just buy a new phone.

Here are some options for IDs

General Android Guidence:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

**Option 1:** Advertising Id
http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html

Cons:
Can be reset by user through settings https://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/20/how-to-reset-your-advertising-id-on-android/

**Option 2:** GUID
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID

Cons
Can be reset by clearing app data or reinstalling

**Option 3:** Hardware Id IMEI
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager

Cons
Requires permission READ_PHONE_STATE (which we already ask for)
Users can toggle off so we wouldn’t have access

**Option 4:** Hardware Id SSAID
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html

Cons
Can be reset by factory resetting phone
Starting in O this will be a per app id instead of a device id which means it can be reset by uninstalling and reinstalling

**Option 5:** ANDROID_ID
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID

Cons
Users can create a new one by creating a new user on the device
Reset with factory reset as well
Can be null

Comment: Great thank you for the amazing info I will use the IMEI i guess, people will either have to let the app know the IMEI or they won't get the feature

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the IMEI number and block based on it. Make sure to get and save it somewhere during installation phase and add a step for IMEI verification once you install to check if it is blocked or not. 
Let me know if you can find another way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Hope it will help, can you upvote it to reach more people ?